# Max speedup in pipelined CPU

Tags: cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Calculating the maximum speedup of a single cycle CPU converted into a 5 stage pipelined CPU.

Single cycle has a time of 800ps

The pipelined stages are separated by registers that take time 40ps.

What I have so far is:

> 800/(40*5) = max speedup of 4.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

we are not supposed to do your homework.
if you assume that you can split the operations evenly into 5 stages and data dependencies are ignored, then the speedup would be 800/(160+40)=4

Comment: I never asked you to do my homework. I gave an example of what I had done for the answer and asked if it was being done correctly. I never said "please do this for me", I wanted to know if it was right. I'm allowed to ask questions that ask for help on homework as long as I've shown a summary of what I had done so far.